# How can I check if the character equal space?

Tags: java, string, character

I need to check if the array of character [i] equal space or not

**Please look at the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\tplease enter text");
    System.out.print("\t");
    String text = in.next();

    for(int i =0;i<text.length();i++)
    {
        if(text.charAt(i) == 'a') // case a
        {
            System.out.println("it is  > a");
        }
        else if(text.charAt(i) == ' ') // case space
        {
            System.out.println("it is a  > space");
        }
    }
    
    
}// main
```

}

Whene (text.charAt(i) == ' ') TRUE
It doesn't do the statement

Comment: Please do not tag spam. Tag only the language that the code is written in.

Comment: Why would you tag this with c and c++?

Comment: `in.next()` is going to tokenize on whitespace. Use `in.nextLine()` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking it maybe c, cpp and java have the same issue

Comment: By the way, `charAt` is legacy, and yields surprising results when used with characters outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). Learn to use code point integers instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text.charAt(i) == ' '` will not be true since you use `Scanner`'s `next` method and thus your `text` variable will not contain a space.

By default a `Scanner`'s delimeter is whitespace, so your call of

```
String text = in.next();
```

will cause `text` to only contain data up until the first space of your input. You can verify this using a `System.out.println(text)`.

Use `String text = in.nextLine();` instead.